# How to scroll to the index when creating a widget?

Tags: list, flutter, scroll

I use ***scrollable_positioned_list*** to scroll to the widget. But for some reason, scrolling ***only*** happens after hot reloading. How do I make scrolling happen immediately when creating a widget?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, it was enough to add **initialScrollIndex** to **ScrollablePositionedList**.

*Read the documentation, guys!*

Comment: The question is not properly built.